# I want to add an additional space within this jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, jsx

```
showResults = () => {
    return (
        <div>
          <p> {this.state.queryData.map((i, index) => index+1 + " :" + i)} </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I would like this to return something like:

```
1. "Blah blah blah" 
2. "Blah blah blah"
```

Right now it looks like:

```
1. "Blah blah blah" 2. "Blah blah blah"
```

Comment: Looks like a list. You could use `ol` and `li` to make it semantic

Comment: You can add a <br /> when rendering each children

Comment: Do you want add a space or do you want the result to be a numbered list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the children in a div.

```
showResults = () => {
  return(
    <div>
     <p> {this.state.queryData.map((i, index) => <div>{index+1 + " :" + i}</div>)} </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

or better yet, do the map and then add the "p" inside

```
showResults = () => {
  return(
    <div>
     {this.state.queryData.map((i, index) => <p>{index+1 + " :" + i}</p>)}
    </div>
  )
}
```